# Strange parsing behavior _Atomic with templates

Tags: c++, c, atomic

```
//clang 3.8.0

#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
_Atomic T* get_atomic(T* val) {
    return reinterpret_cast<_Atomic T*>(val);
}

int main()
{

    volatile int val = 1;
    _Atomic volatile int* val_ptr = reinterpret_cast<_Atomic volatile int*>(&val);
    // works as expected
    std::cout << *val_ptr;
    // Fails due to "_Atomic cannot be applied to qualified type 'volatile int'"
    //std::cout << "Hello, world!\n" << *get_atomic(&val);
}
```

Why is there a discrepancy between the way the template expansion is parsed and the way that the explicit expansion is parsed? They should be identical. Is there a way to ensure that _Atomic is treated as a qualifier in the presence of template arguments?

Comment: Note that any identifier that starts with an underscore, followed by a capital letter is *reserved for the implementation*. `_Atomic` is *not* a valid name for you to use in your own code.

Comment: @JesperJuhl - It's an invalid identifier for you to **name** your own things by. If an implementation provides it and documents it than you may *use it*.

Comment: @StorryTeller - Correct. Good clarification. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword `_Atomic` comes from C (C11) and is not a keyword in C++. In C++ atomics are specified via `std::atomic`. The best would be not to mix syntactical concepts of the two languages.

If you have to mix code that accesses atomic data from both languages, you should deal with the atomic types such as `std::atomic_int`, or invent some macro interfaces similar to the following

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define myAtomic(T) std::atomic< T >
#else
#define myAtomic(T) _Atomic(T)
#endif
```

On any reasonal platform these should be binary compatible.

Comment: Some C++ standard library implementations of std::atomic and friends are built using the C11 _Atomic primitives and compiler builtins. The functionality described in the question would have enabled a more succinct implementation of std::atomic_ref (see https://reviews.llvm.org/D72240/new/). In general it is definitely best to prefer the C++ atomic classes and functions to the C11 ones.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug in either the spec or clang. To work around it, you can use the following trick to restore the qualifiers on the original type:

```
//clang 3.8.0

#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct Impl {
    T __a_value;
    using underlying_t = T;
    Impl(T val) : __a_value(val) {}
};

template <typename Tp_, typename Original_>                                                                                        
struct __annotate_with_qualifiers {                                                                                                 
  using __const_qualified = typename std::conditional<std::is_const<Original_>::value, const Tp_, Tp_>::type;                                 
  using __type = typename std::conditional<std::is_volatile<Original_>::value, volatile __const_qualified, __const_qualified>::type;          
};                                                                                                                                  

template<typename _Tp>                     
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY inline                                                                                                    
typename __annotate_with_qualifiers<_Atomic(typename _Tp::underlying_t), _Tp>::__type*            
__cxx_atomic_pointer_to_data(_Tp* __value) {                                                                                        
  return reinterpret_cast<typename __annotate_with_qualifiers<_Atomic(typename _Tp::underlying_t), _Tp>::__type*>(&__value->__a_value);                                                                                                       
}

template<typename T>
void print_val(const volatile T* val) {
    std::cout << "Const volatile " << *val << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void print_val(const T* val) {
    std::cout << "Const " << *val << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void print_val(volatile T* val) {
    std::cout << "Volatile " << *val << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void print_val(T* val) {
    std::cout << "Plain " << *val << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Impl<int> val(1);
    volatile Impl<int> val2(2);
    const Impl<int> val3(3);
    const volatile Impl<int> val4(4);
    print_val(__cxx_atomic_pointer_to_data(&val));
    print_val(__cxx_atomic_pointer_to_data(&val2));
    print_val(__cxx_atomic_pointer_to_data(&val3));
    print_val(__cxx_atomic_pointer_to_data(&val4));
}
```